# Facebook feed post public {EVERYONE} javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am using java-script code to post on Facebook wall through graph-api. My content is successfully posted on wall but the privacy setting display post to "friends" only, i need to post my content as "public" display to every one. 
below are my code:

```
var data=
{
         message : 'Ateam4adream',
         name : 'Ateam4adream virtual project management',
         privacy: {'value': 'EVERYONE'},
         description : 'Sugerblock description #medicine #e-commerce (endorsed)',
         picture : 'http://techphant.com/img/portfolio/SugarBlock4.jpg',

 }
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', data, responsefunction);
```

I am using facebook reference guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post

Answer (score 0):

Privacy settings are completely up to the user, you can´t change it to `public` if the user only selected `friends`. You can only change it to a smaller group of people, as you can read in the docs about the privacy parameter:

> This field cannot be used to set a more open privacy setting than the one granted

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you only allowed the app to post under '**Friends**'. If so, even though you specify post privacy to be public, it defaults to `Friends`. So, in order to be able to post publicly, you must first grant the app with "Public" privacy settings.

As said, privacy setting cannot be set to more open than what it was approved for.
[image: login_screen]